# Numbers: Grouping daily data into weekly data

Tags: numbers

I have a spreadsheet where I am keeping track of several statistics on a daily basis.

I have another spreadsheet where I am keeping track of several statistics on a weekly basis.

I want to graph the data together. In order to do this, I want to aggregate the first (daily) set of data into weekly data. This will enable to me to get it all on the same graph so I can better visualize it.

Suggestions?

--

Apple makes searching for help hard by calling their product "Numbers".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figured this out, finally. Thanks, community!

I created a table with weekly dates. Then I added summary columns for the daily data:

```
=SUMIFS(
  column_I_care_about_from_daily_spreadsheet,
  date_field_in_daily_spreadsheet, ">="&date_in_this_spreadsheet, 
  date_field_in_daily_spreadsheet, "<"&date_in_this_spreadsheet
)
```

I then added a "summary" column to match the weekly data

```
=SUMIF(
  date_field_in_daily_spreadsheet,
  "="&$date_in_this_spreadsheet,
  column_I_care_about_from_daily_spreadsheet
)
```

Two things:
- Yes, the second formula is overkill
- Yes, SUMIF and SUMIFS reverse their fields from each other

From here, I could easily get a graph.